# Update UI State in Realtime after Room Database Changes using Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Jetpack Compose Picture App where the user views Cached Photos from ROOM Database. The database has a `isFavorite` column which stores Booleans and is updated when the user clicks to like the photo.

This is my ***dao***

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM astrophotoentity")
suspend fun getSavedAstroPhotos(): Flow<List<AstroPhotoEntity>>

@Query("UPDATE astrophotoentity SET isFavorite =:isFavorite WHERE id=:id")
suspend fun updateIsFavoriteStatus(id: String,isFavorite:Boolean)
```

This is my ***Repository*** code

```
override suspend fun updateIsFavoriteStatus(photo: AstroPhoto, isFavorite:Boolean) {
        dao.updateIsFavoriteStatus(photo.date,isFavorite)
    }
```

I am using a ***use case class*** for clean architecture.

class UpdateIsFavoriteStatusUseCase (private val repository: AstroRepository) {

```
suspend operator fun invoke(photo: AstroPhoto, isFavorite:Boolean){

    repository.updateIsFavoriteStatus(photo, isFavorite)
}
```

}

I also use a ***simple data class to hold state*** for the ViewModel.

```
data class PhotoState(
    val astroPhotos: List<AstroPhoto> = emptyList(),
    val isPhotosListLoading: Boolean = false,
    val errorMessage: String? = null)
```

This is the ***ViewModel*** which initializes the Photo State list to a list fetched from the DB. I use `mutableStateOf()` to hold the photo objects list. Here I update isFavorite column in the database depending on the passed event.

```
 @HiltViewModel
    class OverviewViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val useCaseContainer: UseCaseContainer
    ) : ViewModel() {
    
        var state by mutableStateOf(PhotoState())
            private set
    
    init {

//set the state to the retrieved list of photo objects
... getPhotosListFromDb() 
}
    
     fun onEvent(event: OverviewEvent) { ....

     is OverviewEvent.OnMarkFavorite -> { ....
    
      useCaseContainer.updateIsFavoriteStatus(event.photo, event.isFavorite)}
    
      is OverviewEvent.OnRemoveFromFavorites -> { ....
            
    useCaseContainer.updateIsFavoriteStatus(event.photo, event.isFavorite)}
```

I pass the Photos list to the below ***composable***.

```
@Composable
fun AstroPhotoComposable(
photo: AstroPhoto,
onMarkAsFavorite: () -> Unit,
onRemovePhoto: () -> Unit = {}
) {
//retrieve the isFavorite state using photo.isFavorite and cache it
  var isFavorite by remember{ mutableStateOf(photo.isFavorite) ... }
```

The issue I am facing is that when the photo changes from `isFavorite/!isFavorite` the state is not reflecting live on the UI.

I have read somewhere about cold and hot kotlin flows but I'm yet to wrap my head around this. I also tried to replace `mutableStateOf` with `MutableStateFlow` but the state is not updating on Database Changes.

Basically, I am looking to observe for database changes and get an up-to-date state similar to `LiveData`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever tried updating the whole entity?

```
@Update
suspend fun update(myEntity: myEntity): Int
```

And in my opinion it has to be without suspend

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM astrophotoentity")
fun getSavedAstroPhotos(): Flow<List<AstroPhotoEntity>>
```

I'd do it like that.

```
fun getSavedAstroPhotos() = dao.getSavedAstroPhotos().map{ it.toPhotoState() }
```

And collect it in view model

```
 init {
   viewModelScope.launch { 
        getSavedAstroPhotos().collect{
            state = it
        }
    }
 }
```

Perhabs it helps you [link](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-room-flow#8)

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I am wondering why is `update()` dao function returning an `Int` and where is the returned `Int` value used.

Comment: An @Update method can optionally return an int value indicating the number of rows that were updated successfully. You can read it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data)